# Using Index Match to find values contained within cells

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to get index match to to search for things more generically.

Col A  | Column B 
1234      | 9514, 6548, 3181, 9516
2356      | 1458, 1234, 1594
4568      | 9874
1594      | 9845, 9841
1563      | 4568
NOTE: Column A & Column B are in 2 different excel sheets

Match would normally only pick up "4568"(it's in the last row of Column B) but I would also like to find "1234" (it's in the second row of Column B).

Comment: [Why can't people use google?](https://exceljet.net/formula/partial-match-against-numbers-with-wildcard)

Comment: @vacip :) :) or press F1

Comment: @vacip I tried that and I'm getting #N/A. And before you ask, yes the value is in the column i'm looking at.

Answer (score 0):

Works for me:

[image]

The Formula:

```
=MATCH("*"&A1&"*";Sheet2!$A$1:$A$5&"";0)
```

Enter it as an array formula. If you don't know what an array formula is, please use google and spend 30 minutes understanding and testing the concept.

If you don't understand the formula, just say so.

Cheers.